# Adding a new custom shipping field in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'd like to add a new custom billing field in my woocommerce checkout. After adding the following code inside my child theme functions.php, saved it and refreshed the page, I received a blank page. There was no error message. I believe there must be syntax error or something.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
   $fields['shipping']['about_yourself'] = array(
      'label' => __('About yourself', 'woocommerce'),
      'placeholder' => _x('About yourself', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
      'required' => false,
      'class' => array('form-row-wide');
      'clear' => true
   );
   return $fields;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: change     'class' => array('form-row-wide'); to 'class' => array('form-row-wide'), in your code

Answer (score 5):

The error is in your array field that should be like:

```
$fields['shipping']['about_yourself'] = array(
  'label' => __('About yourself', 'woocommerce'),
  'placeholder' => _x('About yourself', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
  'required' => false,
  'class' => array('form-row-wide'), 
  'clear' => true
);
```

**NOTE:** During development process to enable the `error_reporting()` and set WP_DEBUG true. This is how you enable it during WordPress development in wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you all. It works now. It's a very clumsy mistake I have made here. Thanks Jogesh_pi for your advice - For I have enabled the error_reporting and set WP_DEBUG to true.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `;` instead of `,` in `'class' => array('form-row-wide');`

So your code would be :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields');
    function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
       $fields['shipping']['about_yourself'] = array(
          'label' => __('About yourself', 'woocommerce'),
          'placeholder' => _x('About yourself', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
          'required' => false,
          'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
          'clear' => true
       );
       return $fields;
}
```